# Typescript - Create a function off an entity to check a property value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following entity in my typescript file in my Angular 7 app:

```
export class FeedbackType {
    id: number;
    name: String;
}
```

I want to be create a function off this entity which checks the value of a property, such as:

```
feedbackType.IsGreat();
```

I tried the below after some research:

```
export class FeedbackType {
    id: number;
    name: String;

    public isGreat() {
        return this.name === 'Great';
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> feedbackType.isGreat is not a function

---

This is similar to in C# the following method:

```
public static bool IsGreat(this FeedbackType feedbackType)
{
    return feedbackType.name == "Great";
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the instance `feedbackType` of type `FeedbackType`? Second, you are calling `feddbakType.IsGreat()` (with capital I) but you defined `public isGreat()` method (with lowercase i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

```
export class FeedbackType {
    constructor(private id: number, private name: string) {}
    isGreat() { return this.name === 'Great'; };
}
```

and use it as:

```
let ft: FeedbackType = new FeedbackType(0, 'Great');
if (ft.isGreat()) {
   //do stuff
}
```